# Can anyone suggest me any algebraic topology books which are written in a lucid language than Allen Hatcher but in that same pattern?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology

Can anyone suggest me any algebraic topology books which are written in a lucid language than Allen Hatcher but in that same pattern. If someone of Mathstack member has written or they know some easy pdf notes on this topics please let me know. It will be of a great help.

Comment: Yeah I have seen this. No positive answer. It was posted  in 2014. Don't know whether I will get any extra name now. Again if any pdf notes will be available, it will also be a help.

Comment: I haven't read Fulton's book on algebraic topology, but his book Algebraic Curves is extremely well written and lucid so I'd say it's a good bet.  And I'm not among the most brilliant readers so I'm talking about for the mortal.